# PrimeFaces with lazy loading and custom filterModes

Tags: primefaces, datatables, filtering, lazy-loading

I have problem figuring out how to incorporate filtering such as this: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
(for example that sales status)

into my lazy loaded datatable based on this: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

The second example is my base (I only created Car according to the attributes and fixed LazySorter's compare and LazyCarDataModel's load so the applications does not crash and does what it should and it works for me same as the the example on primefaces webpage). So the basic filterBy is functional.

I realize that the filtering with Lazy Load is done in load() function but how to call that load with my custom filter? How to add those filtering methods used in FilterView? They use "PF('carsTable').filter()" in my case carTable but it does nothing. How to somehow connect it with my load function?

(I found several similar but not same problems and solutions or and I tried to decode and use them. I did not manage to make it work so far.)

Additional challenge to solve (if someone would be so great to care :D): Separating those filters into my own buttons not embedded into the datatable (like commandLink or commandButtons).

I'll be grateful for any help. If you need to see my code I can provide it but those examples are basically it and its nicely structured and formated.

Comment: You implement it IN your load method. The two are sort of mutually exclusive.

Comment: I understand that but can you point me a little bit how? I mean how to connect the Primefaces frontend with that load method to execute properly when the filtering in datatable is being executed and somehow passing that filter parameters to that load method?

Comment: That is all in the PrimeFaces showcase

Comment: I know but I dont understand how to connect the filter with the load function or is it somehow managed automatically but how? It is not explained there and I failed to find it sufficently explained elsewhere. I know I might be asking for something which is trivial to most people working with it, but I just cant get it. :(

Comment: Check the example in the showcase. It is all in there. Also check the documentation. I think you are looking for something that is automatically done. Hence you can't find any docs/examples of what you **think** is needed